# code review request WIT customization TFS

Tags: tfs

i would like to add a field to the code review request WIT, and display that in the code review request page or team explorer. is this possible in TFS?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Code Review Request and Response work item types can be customized like any other work item types. The process is the same as with normal work items.

Use `witadmin exportwitd` to export the type definition, edit it and then import it back into the server using `witadmin importwitd`. Alternatively edit the process template offline and import the whole new process template before creating a new project.

See:

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd312129.aspx

Comment: thanks for your response. is there any way to display those edited work item fields in Team Explorer?.

Comment: Not directly. You can install the Team Foundation Server Power Tools which allow you to edit the Work Item Definition. You'll need to download the version of the Power Tools that matches your Visual Studio and TFS version. => https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/site/search?query=team%20foundation%20server%20power%20tools&f%5B0%5D.Value=team%20foundation%20server%20power%20tools&f%5B0%5D.Type=SearchText&ac=5